# Disabled first-chance-exception but debugger stopps within try...catch when using IronPython

Tags: c#, exception, ironpython, first-chance-exception

The following code should be executed without stopping the debugger:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("Foo.Do()");
var compiledCode = source.Compile(new PythonCompilerOptions { Optimized = true });

try
{
    compiledCode.Execute(
         engine.CreateScope(
            new Dictionary<string, object> { 
                                            { "Foo", new Foo() }
                                           }));

    MessageBox.Show("Executed without error");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error at execution: {0}", ex.Message));
}
```

Using this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Do()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The debugger should not break here...");
    }
}
```

The script execution runs in a try-block to handle any exception. 
If I have code like `1 / 0` all works perfekt. The exception is created in Python (or in the engine) and my catch-block is called as expected without forcing the debugger to stop anywhere.

Calling `try { new Foo().Do(); } catch {}` in C# does also work without stopping the debugger.

But throwing an exception in C#-code that's invoked in python will force the debugger to stop at the `throw new...`-line.

I don't want the debugger to stop there.

I disabled the first-chance-exceptions in `Debug/Exceptions` but the debugger still stops at throw.

I can't use `DebuggerStepThrough` because in my working code the exception it not thrown in this method but deeper in the code. The code is also used out of C# and decorating all these methods with `DebuggerStepThrough` will make my C# debugger obsolete.

A solution is to disable `User-unhandled` exceptions in `Debug/Exceptions` too but I want to break at exceptions that aren't handled by the user so this is not an option.

What can I do to disable the first-chance-exception called out of python code that's executed in a try...catch block?

Comment: Does the Python code contain try/catch?  Presumably it doesn't, now it does get to be a judgement call where the "best" place for the debugger break should be located.  Somewhat predictably, that won't be at a place where the Python code is no longer runnable and the actual source of the exception is no longer visible.  You'd have to delete the PDB file for that C# code to convince the debugger that it is not "My Code".

Comment: Do you see any? No it only contains `Foo.Do()`. I couldn't delete the PDB's because there's a lot of other code that should be debugged normally.

Comment: I didn't see any, you didn't post your Python code.  Was there any point in being snarky about it?

Comment: Please have a look at my posted C# code: `engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("Foo.Do()");` Here it is... There's no hidden code...

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have a default option checked in your Debugging settings that's causing this:

[image]

Make sure that box is unchecked and you should be good to go.  Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Great idea. Haven't checked that before. ... This checkbox is unchecked but the debugger still stops :-(